# Generating mail from template

Tags: c#, .net, razorengine

#### Story

I want to generate a mail from a template.

The template would look similar to this:

```
<h1>@Model.Name</h1>
@foreach(var row in Model.Rows)
{
    <p>@row</p>
}
@if(Model.Case)
{
    <p>Thats the case</p>
}
```

Those templates are stored in the database, every user has few(~10) of them and they may be modified.

Until now, we used RazorEngine, we would simply always call `Razor.Parse()`. This worked fine for us, until we had problems with disk space.
(Parse() generates a new assembly on every call in a temp folder, so there are quite a lot of them)

---

#### What I tried

So I thought I need to switch to use RazorEngines new features `Compile(), Run(), RunCompile()` thinking it would be possible to Compile the template (gave it the DB-Id as template key) when changes would be made so I had only one assembly per template. I then would call 'Run()' when I need the mail with the data. But that is not possible. Another problem would be the Memory Leak because every template assembly will stay in the cache.

We also looked at stringtemplate.org (c# development state doesn't look great) and Microsofts MailDefinition (can only be used for variables, doesn't support loops...)

---

#### What I am looking for

Basically I am looking for a RazorEngine which doesn't cache anything. I used `Razor.Parse()` and have not had any performance issues.

Is there a setting in RazorEngine, I did not see, to disable the caching? Is there an alternative to RazorEngine which does that? Or is there even a different method to generate mails from a template?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [T4 Text Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx)? You can build [design-time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd820620.aspx) or [run-time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844259.aspx) text templates that "compile" to anything. A few examples of this in the real world:

- Entity Framework uses these to generate your C# model files (.cs)
- You can use T4 templates to generate .sql files (or just SQL statements) containing C# code (variables, conditions, etc) which gets executed at runtime
- ASP.NET MVC uses T4 templates behind the scenes when generating views and controllers using scaffolding

"Executing" the template is as easy as one line of code:

```
var templateOutput = new MyTemplateClass().TransformText();
```

There are more advanced options, such as passing in parameters/variables to the template, which are documented well in MSDN.